# Laravel and Mamp Localhost Error 500 Mac

Tags: php, macos, laravel

So after a fresh install of laravel (v5.4) and using Mamp as my local server I just get (in chrome)

```
The localhost page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

I've tried countless things like changing permissions on storage or everything within the laravel directory.

Done composer update/install in the directory.

I'm running PHP v7.0.12 on my Mac (10.11.6). Cant think of anything else that would be causing this?

If I create another directory which a simple index.php with '' it loads absolutely fine so what is causing an issue with laravel?

Here's pics of my mamp setup

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg3lV.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNUU1.png

Comment: Are you using the correct url? Laravel requests always start in the public folder. So if you installed a Laravel instance in the public folder of your localhost, you need to access it via `localhost/public`

Comment: Check your storage/log/laravel.log file. It will have more information about error.

Comment: As far as I'm aware I should be accessing it via localhost:8888 (mamp opens the start page at http://localhost:8888/MAMP/?language=English). I've set the directory for the server to laravel/public so shouldn't need to access via /public

Comment: What's your apache configuration?

Comment: Have added links to screenshots of mamp config in original post

Comment: Did you run composer install in your base directory?

Answer (score 1):

Open up terminal and type:

```
tail -n 20 /Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log
```

This may give you some clue as to what is going on.

Hope this helps, happy coding :)

Comment: This is what I got (bare in mind I did a fresh install?) - https://pastebin.com/wVC8NJjC

Comment: Appears PHP version keeps changing now dependant on directory and the version inside my laravel directory gives me 5.5.36. How do I go about changing this version to 7 globally?

Comment: You can download the version you require from http://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/\

**Also** Mamp only allows 2 versions of php to show up. Quick fix, rename the folders you're not bothered about using, for me this meant adding an "X" to to my /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10_X folder. Now your current version and 7.0.0  show up in the mamp prefs.

Done!

Comment: Think I've managed to get it to work now. Managed to get php 5.6.30 with php -v but i do need to do composer install after a fresh install of laravel it appears. EDIT: Tell a lie, closed terminal, reopned and the version of php has changed back to 5.5.36, whats going on?

Comment: So in my .bash_profile I had `export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.27/bin:$PATH`, I run source ~/.bash_profile and it shows the correct version (5.6.27). If I quit terminal and reopen and do php -v it gives me 5.5.36. Why is this not saving?

Answer (score 0):

I just joined stackoverflow yesterday so I do not have enough reputation to comment. I write an answer here.

here is the short answer:

run :

```
PHP_VERSION=`ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/ | sort -n | tail -1`
echo "export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/${PHP_VERSION}/bin:$PATH" >> .bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

**check your php version by running php -v. close the terminal. Open another terminal and check php version again.if you see php 5 again then there are 2 possibilities:
First: you added the `/path/to/php7` after `/path/to/php5` and php 5 is loaded first.
Second: system loads another bash file first which your php 5 path is mentioned in it. I know that this sounds confusing having several bash file but it is. Please search for other files like `bashrc` or similars.**

This is the long answer for anyone else:

first of all, if you are on mac, I highly suggest you to use **valet** to get rid of all these things.

But regarding the problem:

As you already noted that it is not a laravel issue. the php version that your machine uses is under the min required version by laravel. You have 2 versions of php at the moment. MacOs is shipped with php installed on that. I think it is the same php 5.5.36 that is making problem for you. Since Laravel 5.4, you need to use **PHP >= 5.6.4**.
Although you have installed parallel php 7 on your machine, you need also to check which php your machine is reading from by running `which php`. after that remember to add your path to php 7 installed to `bash_profile` or other bash files on your mac(you can have 4 or 5 bash files). 
Considering you have only one bash file named as bash_profile and you are going to export the path to your php 7 to bash profile, If you run following command, that appends the path to the end of file

```
PHP_VERSION=`ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/ | sort -n | tail -1`
echo "export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/${PHP_VERSION}/bin:$PATH" >> .bash_profile
```

remember to use `source ~/.bash_profile` in order to make changes effected. 
Alternatively you can open the bash_profile file in your text editor by running:

```
open -a /Applications/TextEdit.app ~/.bash_profile
```

and add the path manually before the `/path/to/php5` path.

finally you must check your php version by running `php -v`. 
close the terminal. Open another terminal and check php version again. If you see php 7 then you are all fine. But if you see php 5 again then there are 2 possibilities:
First: you added the `/path/to/php7` after `/path/to/php5` and php 5 is loaded first.
Second: system loads another bash file first which your php 5 path is mentioned in it. I know that this sounds confusing having several bash file but it is. Please search for other files like `bashrc` or similars.